# Can I prevent the sending of messages when an iOS app is in Guided Access?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, messages, guided-access

In Guided Access mode of iOS the device enters a single app mode and you can block access to certain parts of the screen. Guided Access is enabled through Settings > Accessibility > Guided Access (in 4th block "General") and then started with a triple-click of the side button in the app you want to use. This is particularly helpful when handing your device to your kids and you don't want them to mess with the other apps.

One thing that I haven't been able to block though is access to Messages. In some apps you can tap "Share" and then the user would be able to share something via Messages. While I can block certain parts of the screen, a share button can be on different parts of the screen throughout the app, so covering that part isn't necessarily helpful. Is there a way to disable the sending of messages or sharing altogether?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this also.